# I am having some issues in understanding PHP variable syntax in a WordPress string

Tags: php, string, wordpress, variables

I have the following line in some code I am trying to modify to include an image from my theme directory.

```
protected $_branding = 'Site Design by <a href="http://www.mysite.com">MySite</a>.';
```

So, what I want is:

```
protected $_branding = 'Site Design by <a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="(((My ThemeFolder)))/images/myimage.png" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;"/>MySite</a>.';
```

What is returned seems to output exactly what is inside the parent quotes. So, I am assuming this is some kind of string. So, how do I make it include a PHP variable to get my theme folder without having to hard code it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
protected $_branding = 'Site Design by <a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/myimage.png" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;"/>MySite</a>.';
```

Read more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Answer (score 1):

You want `get_template_directory_uri()`

```
protected $_branding = 'Site Design by <a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/myimage.png" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;"/>MySite</a>.';
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri for the documentation.

Comment: Hmmm.... This is exactly what I had tried. Since this is being built inside an array, the periods to break it.

Comment: what do you mean? Your code didn't have any arrays in it - if you want an answer that fits better, edit your code to include the problematic part, otherwise we can't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

Here are different functions for your reference..

```
get_template_directory(): Returns the absolute template directory path.
get_template_directory_uri(): Returns the template directory URI.
get_stylesheet_directory(): Returns the absolute stylesheet directory path.
get_stylesheet_directory_uri(): Returns the stylesheet directory URI.
```

for your use-case try:

```
protected $_branding = 'Site Design by <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="' .    get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/myimage.png" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;"/>MySite</a>.';
```

docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

also access docs for other functions by http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/{function_name_here}